# How to combine two generic methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have to two extensions:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Existing<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry) 
    where T : class, IDeletable
{
    return qry.Where(...);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Existing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> qry) 
    where T : class, IDeletable
{
    return qry.Where(...);
}
```

How do I combine those two methods into one method? I tried the following:

```
public static TU Existing<TU, T>(this TU qry)
    where TU : class, IQueryable<T>, IEnumerable<T>
    where T : class, IDeletable
{
    return (TU)qry.Where(...);
}
```

But this doesn't work because the type can't be inferred correctly (because IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable, I guess). Moreover, `T` isn't always `IQueryable`, which also seems to be a problem here (question: if I specify multiple interfaces in the where clause, aren't those matched in a disjunctive manner?). In the previous case `IQuerable` was used if it suited or else `IEnumerable`. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt will *always* limit it to `IQueryable<T>` implementations. I assume you really want it to work for both in-process queries and out-of-process queries. Assuming that the "..." in the `Where` clause is a lambda expression, you need to be aware that even if you have the same code in both methods, the compiler will be handling them very differently - because it will already have applied overload resolution to determine the `Where` implementation to use.

I would strongly advise you to leave the two separate overloads as they are.

Comment: Why will it always limit it to `IQueryable`? If I have multiple interfaces in the where clause, aren't those matched in a disjunctive manner? Why can't it just match an `IEnumerable` if it isn't an `IQueryable`?

Comment: @duedl0r: No, if you have multiple interface constraints the type argument has to satisfy *all* of them. So specifying `IEnumerable<T>` is actually redundant. See section 4.4.4 of the C# 4 spec: "A compile-time error occurs if one or more of a type parameter’s constraints are not satisfied by the given type arguments."

Answer (score 2):

```
public static IQueryable<T> Existing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> qry) where T : class, IDeletable
{
    return qry.Where(/*...*/).AsQueryable();
}
```

Calling `AsQueryable` on something that is already queryable will do nothing. Also, IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable, so first: you can pass an IQueryable to this method, and second: the result is actually an IEnumerable as well as an IQueryable.

Comment: Yay! :) Mark as answer if it does. ;)